# Is it possible to customize markdown rendering in a Jupyter notebook to add custom links?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I want to add a custom link syntax in the Markdown cells in a Jupyter notebook so that I can have a Markdown cell that looks like this:

`See Cell ref:label-1 for example`

And the "ref:label-1" would be rendered as a hyperlink that when clicked on would jump to a cell in the notebook that was somehow labeled with "label-1". The hyperlink would also have a tooltip that shows the cell contents.

Is anything like this even possible? I have not found any starting points to build from so far.

Comment: Can be helpful - https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_ipython_internal_links.html

Comment: That would get close to providing links, but I want a customized Markdown syntax and rendering. This wouldn't, for example, let you put tooltips on the link that were useful. I have modified the question to reflect that.